# Android studio 3.0 Canary 6 A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$FileGenerationWorkAction

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

All was fine until i updated the android studio to Canary 6, When i rebuild or clean or whatever with project it's throw :

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$FileGenerationWorkAction

And this error guide me to my `vectors.xml` [All of them got this error]
.

My Current app level **build.gradle** :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 42
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        //multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'//<-- can't update to new one
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Also when i tried to download `com.android.support` libraries, The IDE just search for the sdk and just do nothing.

What i have been tried :

- Clean and Rebuild.
- Invalidate Caches.

Comment: There is a lot of problems with android studio canary 6, i advice  you to work on android studio 2.3.3 or change your class path in th dependencies to 2.3.3

Comment: Canary 4 is more stable than 5/6, especially if you use Kotlin + ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The advantage of adding a multi-density vector graphic is to use a vector instead of a bitmap to reduce the size of the APK because the size of the same file can be adjusted for different screen densities without loss off image quality. For older versions of Android that don't support vector drawables, Vector Asset Studio can, at build time, turn your vector drawables into different bitmap sizes for each screen density

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha8
```

build.gradle

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Adding `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to defaultConfig of build.gradle(Module) worked for me. **:)**

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. There were two ways to fix my case:

1. Adding `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`
2. In my drawable vector xml files there were links to `@color`:

   ```
   <path
       android:fillColor="@color/white"
       ...
   ```

   I replaced with

   ```
   <path
       android:fillColor="#fff"
       ...
   ```

   and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot problems with android studio canary 6, the best way to solve that is to change your class path in the dependencies in your gradle to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Comment: you sure that `2.3.3` version will work with the build ecxution ?

Comment: I changed the classpath to 2.3.3 in android studio canary 6 without any problems.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the Android Studio or Gradle build version. It happens in Android Studio 3.0 release build too. The solution is the vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true flag mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just add vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true in defaultConfig, it's work fine for me

```
defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this  to your `build.gradle` under   `defaultConfig`

`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` .

this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with build gradle 3.1.4. Downgrade to 3.1.3 and you should be good to go

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: Downgrades are usually tricky. It is better to think of solutions under the assumption of backwards compatibility...